# PDO- Inserting UNIX_TIMESTAMP in database

Tags: php, pdo, timestamp

I'm trying to insert registration time in database using PDO.
Here's my code.

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO members(firstname,email,pass_hash,user_activation_hash,user_registration_datetime,user_registration_ip,user_agent) VALUES(:fname,:email,:passhash,:user_activation_hash,now(),:user_registration_ip,:user_agent)";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->execute( array(':fname'=>$fname,':email'=>$email,':passhash'=>$hdacc,':user_activation_hash'=>$user_activation_hash,':user_registration_ip'=>$ip,':user_agent'=>$user_agent));
```

This inserts user_registration_datetime is in the format 2014-09-19 16:20:21 but I want it in UNIX_TIMESTAMP format.Here's what I tried,

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) // instead of now()
```

This doesn't works for me.It just inserting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in db.

Comment: What is the field type of the registration field? If it's a datetime it'll always end up looking formatted like that; a unix_timestamp is an integer.

Comment: @Erik Hey it was datetime.I just noticed it.I changed it to int() and works fine.Thank you so much..

Comment: @ Please post your comment as answer.Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

The function **NOW()** generates a formatted date-time string, determined by the time zone of your MySQL server. If you are getting

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

maybe your time zone is not setup

In my opinion it would be best to store times using **UNIX_TIMESTAMP()**, which is in GMT.

If you still want to use DATETIME columns, you can store times using **UTC_TIMESTAMP()** (it formats a date like **NOW()** but expresses it in UTC); it should more or less work the same in all other aspects.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to store your dates as a timestamp, you'll need to use an INTEGER field, as UNIX_TIMESTAMP is stored as an integer (the number of seconds since 1-1-1970, specifically)

If you use a DATETIME field, it'll always be stored as a formatted date.